# Task Factory StartNew Generic

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, task-parallel-library

There is a `Task.Factory.StartNew(Action<Object> action, Object state)` method.  This looks generic.  But, if my "action" is

```
protected void Edit(MyType myType) { }
```

why can't I have

```
MyType x = something;
Task.Factory.StartNew(Edit, x);
```

I get:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'

I can get it to work by adding another method,

```
protected void Edit(object myType) { Edit((MyType)myType); }
```

or I can write

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Edit(x));
```

but I feel like I'm missing something that should allow me to do it the first way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Edit` method group is not convertible to `Action<object>`. You could do

```
Action<MyType> act = Edit;
```

but there is no conversion between `Action<MyType>` and `Action<object>`. If there were you could do

```
Action<object> act = Edit;
act("abc");
```

Comment: Yeah, I think where I went wrong was reading "Action<object>" as if it were "Action<T>".

Answer (score -1):

The method signature for Task.Factory.StartNew is asking for a single-parameter Action<>, so simply create an Action<> instance and use that in your call:

```
protected void Edit( Object myType ){ ... }

MyType x = something;
Action<Object> action = new Action<Object>(Edit);
Task.Factory.StartNew( action, x );
```

or

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action<Object>(Edit), x);
```

You may be able to inline this using lambdas as well (which you noted):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => Edit(x) );
```

Comment: I believe it _might_ be because there's no method signature defined for StartNew(Action<TArg>, Object) but instead StartNew(Action< **Object** >, Object). That means your Edit method with signature void Edit(MyType) isn't matching the Action<Object> being requested. Try changing your method to Edit (Object myType) {...} and see if that works.

Comment: The first two suggestions in this answer do not build.  They both  return the error, 'Argument 1 cannot convert from Action<MyType> to Action<object>' on the StartNew call; the final suggestion was one I had already made.  So, although I always appreciate any help I get here, I did mark this answer down as not useful.  Also, the suggestion in the comment (to change the method) was also already mentioned in my question...

Comment: Kelly, it seems you really answered your own question in a way. The same reason this doesn't work is the same reason this doesn't work (no implicit cast or boxing happens for you):

public delegate void SomeDelegate(Object o);
public void someMethod(String s)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
}

public void doSomething(SomeDelegate del)
{
  del();
}

public function Main() {
  doSomething(someMethod);
}